# Node.js: Query Aggregation not working (mongodb)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

So I'm kinda new to node.js. And I can't understand why Aggregate queries don't work for me. I've tried the same query at the Mongo Shell and it worked perfectly.
Here's the code:

```
db.collection("companies").aggregate({$match:
{$or:
    [{ $and:
        [{ left: {$gt: 2}}, {left: {$lt: 11}}]},
    { $and:
        [{ right: {$gt: 2}}, {right: {$lt: 11}}]}]}},
{ $group:
    {_id:null, 
        Sum:{$sum: "$earn"}}}, 

function(err, data){

    if (err) throw err;

    console.log(data[0]);
    console.log(data.value);
    console.log(data.Sum);
});
```

Console output:

```
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregation argument needs to be an array, because aggregation works on pipeline concept where output of last pipeline will become input for current pipeline.

```
db.collection("companies").aggregate([
{$match:
  {$or:
      [{ $and:
          [{ left: {$gt: 2}}, {left: {$lt: 11}}]},
      { $and:
          [{ right: {$gt: 2}}, {right: {$lt: 11}}]}]
}},
{ $group:
    {_id:null, 
        Sum:{$sum: "$earn"}}}], 

function(err, data){

    if (err) throw err;

    console.log(data[0]);
    console.log(data.value);
    console.log(data.Sum);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for helping!